# Visual Studio Apache Cordova android app icon not updating

Tags: android, visual-studio, apache-cordova

I've got a visual studio apache cordova app which opens up a website I've created.

This works fine (ish... being honest it's a pain in the neck to get working, but it it working now!). The only issue I'm having is despite changing ALL of the icons in the res folders, icon folders etc etc (basically any image within the project) it STILL displays the default icon?!

I've cleaned the project, rebuilt it - everything. Nothing on google on Stack Overflow seems to have the solution and I'm literally at the end of my patience with it now.

Any suggestions at all?

Comment: post your code on how you're pulling your drawables

Comment: Is this what you mean?

`<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>`